# How to make elements not get pushed down in css?

Tags: html, css

I have this

```css
#chevrons>.chevrons-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 62px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: -29px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: -25px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.title {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.desc {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevrons">
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">&#160;</div>
    <div class="desc">Overview</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 1:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah<br/>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 2:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

But the problem is the center one, is getting pushed down. They are all not perfectly vertically aligned. I don't understand why the contents of the center one is making it get pushed down.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

Note: try viewing the full screen version where they all show in 1 line.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're working with inline-level elements (the anchors).

Therefore, the `vertical-align` property gets applied, and its default value is `baseline`.

With different quantities of text, the baseline will shift, altering the position of the element.

Just add `vertical-align: top` to each `a` element.

```
#chevrons>.chevrons-item { vertical-align: top; } /* or another value except `baseline` */
```

```css
#chevrons>.chevrons-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 62px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  vertical-align: top;  /* NEW */
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: -29px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: -25px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.title {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.desc {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevrons">
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">&#160;</div>
    <div class="desc">Overview</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 1:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      <br/>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 2:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you can make the parent a flex container, which will *blockify* every child, and render the `vertical-align` issue moot.

```
#chevrons { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
```

```css
#chevrons {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
  height: 62px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-right: none;
  border-left: none;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:after {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: -29px;
  z-index: -1;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item:before {
  content: '';
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border: 3px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-left: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
  left: -25px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.title {
  color: gray;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#chevrons>.chevrons-item>.desc {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="chevrons">
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">&#160;</div>
    <div class="desc">Overview</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 1:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah
      <br/>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
  <a href="/" class="chevrons-item">
    <div class="title">Step 2:</div>
    <div class="desc">blah blah blah blah</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change `justify-content` at `#chevrons>.chevrons-item` from `center` to `flex-start` to align items at top. Add `vertical-align` property will fix it, but in this case, it will just increase your css rules unnecessarily.